# Google analytic for mobile app showing no response though getting http 200

Tags: android, google-analytics, tracking

I am using google analytic for my android app.I am getting Http 200 in my logcat but when i go to the google analytics website to see the tracking view , it doesn't show me any activity/response. May be i am missing something in the google analytic. here is the code:

1. tracker =GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();

   ```
   tracker.start("UA-40662362-1", 30, this);
   tracker.setDebug(true); 
   tracker.trackPageView("/TrackerActivity");
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics Data is always available on the Google Analytics Dashboard next day.

So check on Analytics dashboard probably after a day for your data.

Moreover , You can send a Screen View using tracker.sendView("TrackerActivity)

Use the below link to track Screen Views and Send event on Google Analytics:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced

Follow below steps to track data for Mobile App using GA:

1-> Login to Google Analytics site

2-> Click on Admin tab

3-> Create a New Account

4-> Choose App

5-> Fill in All relevant details

6-> A Unique tracker ID will be generated

7-> Follow https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced
to send Screen View and Send Event to GA

8-> Make sure your using the unique tracker id provided to you in Step 6

9-> Use your App with GA Changes

10-> Login to Google Analytics Account next day

11-> Click on Account List and Select the same Account - 3

12-> View you All Mobile app data

Comment: i am waiting for a couple of days but finding no result. and getting error whenever i try to use tracker.sendView("activity");

Comment: instead of using UA-40662362-1   when i use UA-40662362-2 . i can track that, it shows me the active users . but for mobile app data it is not showing . Is there anything to set in the website?

Comment: yes in Google Analytics website, you can create accounts for mobile apps, it will generate a unique id , this you shall use in your app and for viewing the data you should see the same dashboard in GA site

Comment: i really don't understand. Okay let me explain to you. I can see from where and what part of the app is using by the user when i use "UA-4066xxxx-2"  in my android app and choose "all web data" in ga. But when i do use "UA-4066xxxx-1"  and choose "all mobile app data"  in ga i can't see the user's activity.

Comment: can you give a sample project which runs perfectly ?

Comment: I have successfully used the https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced to track all my mobile data in ga